# How can I access a specific wave sound on the Roland SPD-SX Pro drum pad?

Tags: percussion

I've watched videos and skimmed the manual but I can't find how to access a specific wave sound.

This drum pad has 1,553 factory sounds, I'm assuming that each one is used in one or more of the many drum kits available on this drum pad. I'd like to use a woodblock in the next song I write and have identified a candidate sound from the sound list that might work for me; sound #1059.

How can I identify sound #1059 so I can play it and record it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don’t know this machine so I will only comment. Since the manual doesn’t list the individual sounds of each kit I suggest you either edit a user kit and replace a sound you don’t need with the wood block or create a new user kit from scratch and include the wood block sound in it.

Comment: My question was totally wrong. It shouldn't be "How can I find a factory kit that has the wave sound I want?"

It should have been "How can I assign a wave sound to a pad on a User Kit?"

John, your idea of creating a new user kit worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: I’m glad it was helpful. Sometimes devices like these have both preset and user kits. Only the user kits can be created or edited.

Comment: You're right. And this instrument/computer is incredibly powerful.  I just need to learn to think like the programmers did to use it to its fullest.

Comment: Please edit your post so that it reflects the question you're trying to ask.